# Rails 3.1 Active Record - loading the parent object in a has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following class structure for an app I'm porting from php to rails:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_headers
  has_many :menu_items, :through => :menu_headers
end

class MenuHeader < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree :parent_id
  has_many :menu_items
  belongs_to :menu
end

class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu_headers
end
```

How would I load the MenuHeader or Menu for a specific MenuItem?

Like:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > @b=Menu.find(1)  #works
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > @b.menu_headers  #works
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 > @b.menu_items    #works

ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > @mi=MenuItem.find(1) #works
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > @mi.menu_headers     #doesn't work
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 > @mi.menus            #doesn't work
```

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need singular associations as follows:

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu_header
  has_one :menu, :through => :menu_header
end
```

Comment: would I need to add menu_item_id to the menu table since the relationship already exists in the other direction? neither `@mi.menu` nor `@mi.menus` seems to be doing it. thx

Comment: Nope, the `through` option means it will look at the `menu_header` association for the `menu`.  Can you double check your ids are matching up in the db, I think this should work.

Comment: hmm.... doesn't seem to be working. Would MenuHeader need a `has_one` or is a `belongs_to` sufficient? thx - definitely a lack of understanding on my part

Comment: Wait, you're right (see last post) - I didn't take the 's' off the menu_headers relationship in MenuItem. thx for help